Get concrete type from opaque type
How I can get a concrete type from an opaque type.
use std::fmt::Display;

fn fx<T: Display>(x: T)-> impl Display {
    x
}


fn main() {
    let y: i32 = fx(10);
    let xy =  y + 10;
    println!("Hello World {}", xy);
}

Got error message
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> main.rs:16:18
   |
10 | fn fx<T: Display>(x: T)-> impl Display {
   |                           ------------ the found opaque type
...
16 |     let y: i32 = fx(10);
   |            ---   ^^^^^^ expected `i32`, found opaque type
   |            |
   |            expected due to this
   |
   = note:     expected type `i32`
           found opaque type `impl std::fmt::Display`
error: aborting due to 1 previous error
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.

I can't add returned value of integer type with anoter integer value cuz real type of returned vale is hidden.

That would kinda defeat the purpose of opaque types.

Essentially, you have the same options as in How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object? for most intents and purposes, except for the actual dispatch, an opaque type is equivalent to a trait object.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/kmdreko this is kind of strange. For example Vlang can  infer types from Interface https://play.vlang.io/p/c69bf5016f

https://stackoverflow.com/users/442760/cafce25 thx i will read it

You can recover the concrete type (if possible, via Any and friends), but it is often considered an anti-pattern in Rust; it makes the abstraction leaky. If impl Display is insufficient for what you want to do with the return type, then you should change the return type (like impl Display + Add<i32>).

Also, use @Khatry (@username) to reply.

You don't that's the real answer. There are workarounds like @kmdreko mentioned, but if you find yourself wanting that, you're doing something very wrong.

You can recover a specific type from an unknown generic by comparing their TypeIds (similar to how Any::downcast works). This requires the types to be 'static and of course it is fallible since fx can change its implementation behind the impl Display at any time:
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::any::TypeId;

fn fx<T: Display + 'static>(x: T)-> impl Display + 'static {
    x
}

fn downcast_owned<T: 'static, U: 'static>(t: T) -> Result<U, T> {
    if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<U>() {
        // SAFETY: this is safe because we've verified that `T` and `U` are the same
        // and thus we can `read`+`forget` to "move" the value from `t` to `u`.
        let u = unsafe { std::ptr::read(&t as *const _ as *const U) };
        std::mem::forget(t);
        Ok(u)
    } else {
        Err(t)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let y = fx(10);
    if let Ok(y) = downcast_owned::<_, i32>(y) {
        let xy = y + 10;
        println!("Hello World {}", xy);
    }
}

Hello World 20

Playground link
As mentioned in the comments, this is generally not a good idea and it would be better to change the return type to more appropriately describe what you want it to do.

You can just spell out the type in its full form. If that doesn't work, you should rethink the logic a bit. Think like the (rust) compiler. If you return an opaque type (basically a trait object), it can only be sure that the functions implemented in the given trait will work on it. You can give it a bit more context, as shown below.
use std::fmt::Display;

fn fx<T: Display>(x: T) -> T /* now returns T instead */ {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let y: i32 = fx(10);
    let xy =  y + 10;
    println!("Hello World {}", xy);
}


I know. But  Rust offers opportunity  use opaque types. And I just wanted to know can I get particular type from it later.
